# Understand `rows-per-page-items` at Vuetify Data iterators + Data tables, can I set default page?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

At Vuetify [docs for Data Tables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables), and [docs for Data Iterators](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-iterator) I do not manage to understand the `rows-per-page-items` prop usage and its options, nor find any in-details explanation at any other place.

Specifically, what I want to know is if one could use the mentioned prop to set the chosen-rows-per-page-amount to a default value **other than the first** in selection.

For example, drop down selection:

```
Items per page:  10
                [20] -> Selected by default
                 30
                 40
```

I know that I can do:

```
Items per page: [20] -> First, so will be selected by default
                 10
                 30
                 40
```

Doing:

```xml
<v-data-iterator :rows-per-page-items="[20, 10, 30, 40]" ... />
```

But the above is not so ideal, UX-wise.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

For anyone using vuetify 2.0 you have to use the footer prop on the data table like so:

```html
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  :footer-props="{
    'items-per-page-options': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
  }"
  :items-per-page="30"
  :search="search"
>
```

Comment: thanks - the difference in the api between 1.5 and 2.0 made this quite hard to find

Comment: @ValijonRahimov use minus 1, e.g. `[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, -1]`

Comment: ```:footer-props="{
    itemsPerPageOptions:[10,20,30,-1]
}"``` as per latest docs

Comment: Moving the solved mark to here since it's the better answer answer about current `vuetify` api. If you are looking for answer about `vuetify` version 1.x please use @Ollywood answer. Also notice the comments above.

Answer (score 41):

You can define the data property as so (if you're using template structure):

```js
rowsPerPageItems: [10, 20, 30, 40],
pagination: {
    rowsPerPage: 20
},
```

and your component tag props:

```html
<v-data-iterator
    :rows-per-page-items="rowsPerPageItems"
    :pagination.sync="pagination"
    ... 
/>
```

The "pagination - rows per page" prop value defines your default.

Comment: Works great! using `pagination` prop! awesome

Comment: How do i add an "all" options to rowsPerPageItems?

Comment: @DeathInWhite It's -1

Comment: Answer is no longer up to date with documentation. API changed

Comment: Moving the solved mark to the answer about `vuetify-2.x`

Answer (score 16):

```
:footer-props="{
    itemsPerPageOptions:[10,20,30,-1]
}"
```

this is the newest version now. the itemsPerPageOptions field in the footer-props.

Comment: thank you this works for me, I understand that `-1 is for display ALL`

Comment: Works! A complete usage example is in the [vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#footer-props), as well as a list of all [available props](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-footer/#api-props).

Answer (score 1):

For vuetify data table

```
<v-data-table
        v-model="selected"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="items"
        select-all
        item-key="name"
        class="elevation-1"
        :rows-per-page-items="[20, 10, 30, 40]"
      >
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using **"vuetify": "^3.4.9"** server side data table 
the document says VDataTable fas a prop **items-per-page-options** with value can be a number or array of Objects you can read documentation [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props-items-per-page-options)

```
(number | { title: string; value: number })[]

[
  {value: 10, title: '10'},
  {value: 25, title: '25'},
  {value: 50, title: '50'},
  {value: 100, title: '100'},
  {value: -1, title: '$vuetify.dataFooter.itemsPerPageAll'}
]
```

```
<v-data-table-server
    v-model="selected"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    select-all
    item-key="name"
    :items-per-page-options="[
        {value: 10, title: '10'},
        {value: 25, title: '25'},
        {value: -1, title: '$vuetify.dataFooter.itemsPerPageAll'}
    ]"
>
</v-data-table-server>
```